# In a run-in-editor script, how do I change the focus of inspector window in cocos creator?

Tags: cocoscreator

In cocos creator I have a custom text component that runs/renders in Editor. I am attempting to update some arrays in its properties programmatically (empty/replace array contents), which works fine in principal but it does generate some Vue errors related to duplicate entries in the Inspector. Since I cannot edit Cocos Creator I am trying to workaround this problem by switching the inspector to a different node or parent node but I can't seem to figure out to get that to work. Any suggestions?  I see Editor.UI.focus but I don't know what parameters to send to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved when upgrading to 2.4.8. Vue errors went away.